# Android call search function programmatically

Tags: android, search, button, listener, android-mapview

In Google Maps, when you click the search box the real search comes up. The search box is just an imageview illusion with an onclicklistener

similarly, if you press the search button on the mobile device, the search box comes up.

I need to implement similar behavior, when the user clicks an image that is over the map (in a relativelayout), the search box for that mapview comes up.

how would I call the mapview's search feature??? I was thinking of just simulating a search button press but I dont even know what this function's name is.

Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `onSearchRequested()`. Just make a call on your `onClickListener`. Complete guide to search implementation can be found here.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html